# Filling up property value in array from already having a range of values - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

$emails = Import-Csv "C:\Testing\Emails.csv"

**$emails**

`Email`

`User-1@test.com`

`User-2@test.com`

`User-3@test.com`

`User-4@test.com`

`User-5@test.com`

`User-6@test.com`

`User-7@test.com`

`User-8@test.com`

`User-9@test.com`

`User-10@test.com`

`.... and So on...`

**$DagSelection**

`DAGname Sr`

`GB-01 1`

`GB-04 2`

`GB-02 3`

`GB-03 4`

```
$DagValues = $DagSelection.dagname
[PSCustomObject]$Array1 = @()
foreach ($x in $DagValues) {$Array1 += 1..100 | foreach {[PsCustomObject] 
@{Databases= $x + "-" + "{0:D3}" -f [int]$_}} }
```

**$Array1**

`Databases`

`GB-01-001`

`GB-01-002`

`GB-01-003`

`GB-01-004`

`GB-01-005`

`.... and So on...`

My Problem is here with the code given below. It fills up the Databases for each email address given in column Email. But, not in loop. cause the range got finished and what i want is to fill it until we have email address in place. That means if range is GB-01-001 to GB-01-100 it should start again from the beginning. Hope I have covered requirement here. Please let me know if any queries.

```
$props = $Array1 | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($prop in $props){$emailsTemp | Add-Member -Name $prop -Value $null -MemberType NoteProperty -Force}
for ($i=0;$i -lt $emailsTemp.count; $i ++){ $emailsTemp[$i].Databases = 
$Array1[$i].Databases}
$emailsTemp
```

**$emailsTemp**

Email                  Testing
`User-1@test.com  GB-01-001`

`User-2@test.com  GB-01-002`

`User-3@test.com  GB-01-003`

`User-4@test.com  GB-01-004`

`User-5@test.com  GB-01-005`

`User-6@test.com  GB-01-006`

`User-7@test.com  GB-01-007`

`User-8@test.com  GB-01-008`

`User-9@test.com  GB-01-009`

`User-10@test.com GB-01-010`

`......`

`User-401@test.com (I want to fill up here as well)`

`User-402@test.com (I want to fill up here as well)`

`User-403@test.com (I want to fill up here as well)`

`........ and so on... Until Email Ids are present in first column named **Email**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Starting Values
$emails = Import-Csv "C:\Testing\Emails.csv"
$DagSelection = Import-Csv "something.csv"
$DagValues = $DagSelection.dagname

#Get Database array
[array]$Databases=$null
ForEach ($x in $DagValues) {        
    For ($i=1;$i -lt 101;$i++) {
        [array]$Databases+=$x+"-"+("{0:D3}" -f [int]$i)
    }
}

#Output Item
class OutputClassItem {
    [string]$Email
    [string]$DB
}

#Zipping together Email Addresses with Databases
#If Database list runs out, repeat from beginning
[array]$OutputArray=$null
$loopcount=0
Do {
    For($j=0;$j -lt $Databases.Count -and $loopcount -lt $emails.Count;$j++) {
        $OutputItem = New-Object -Type OutputClassItem
        $OutputItem.Email=$emails[$loopcount]
        $OutputItem.DB=$Databases[$j]
        [array]$OutputArray+=$OutputItem
        $loopcount++
    }
} While ($loopcount -lt $emails.Count)

$OutputArray | Export-Csv "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Great logic Eric. Thanks for the efforts. But, the output file give something else. It just keep on adding DBs even if Emails are not there. Suppose if i have 2000 Email IDs it should assign DBs till 2000 only and not further. Can you please assist.

Comment: @EricW Sorry Eric. Its my bad before commenting. Actually i wasn't clearing the variables and hence not getting correct output. Your script code completely works. Bingo... :)

Comment: @EricW . I am still facing issues again. It just keep on adding DBs even if Emails are not there. Suppose if i have 1900 Email IDs it should assign DBs till 1900 only and not further. Can you please assist.

Comment: I have a 3 words for you Perfect, Perfect, Perfect. Thanks. ;)